# In C++, How do I store values into a vector that is inside of a vector when the two vectors are of different types?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am writing a program where I need to use the following data structure:

```
struct shape
{  
    std::vector<float> verts; // contains the x & y values for each vertex   
    char type;                // the type of shape being stored.   
    float shapeCol[3];        // stores the color of the shape being stored.   
    float shapeSize;          // stores the size of the shape if it is a line or point
};
```

In my main program I need a vector of type `shape`. How would I store values into the vector inside of the struct shapes using the the vector of struct shapes.

For instance, `vector<shape> myshapes`;

If I wanted to store a value into the first index of my `verts` vector, inside of my first index of my `myshapes` vector  how would I do this?

in pseudo code it would look something like this, with `i` being the index:

```
myshapes[i].vector[i] = 4;   // but I know this is incorrect
```

Would this be easier to implement using a STL list instead and if so what would that syntax look like?

Thanks for the help I am new to vectors so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to replace `i` with the actual variable used in your loop. Maybe `myshapes[0].vector[0]=4;`

Comment: `myshapes[index of shape].verts[index of vertex within that shape]`

Comment: The syntax is going to be the same with `std::list`; the difference is in their implementation and performance in different scenarios.

Comment: std::vector[] is only be used for read (rvalue), i.e. data is available. You have to add the data to vector before you read it with std::vector.push_back or other functions.

Comment: @KevinSUN Not sure exactly what you're saying, but [`std::vector::operator[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/) returns an lvalue (reference or const reference) – that's why you can assign to it. Although calling it with an index that doesn't exist invokes _undefined behavior_.

Comment: @qxz, sorry, std::vector::operator[] is not only for rvalue, which I'm wrong. What I mean is that he should use push_back or other functions to add items firstly. you can not use operator[] to add a new item in array. Just considering he is new for the vector.

Comment: @KevinSUN I think that is the issue I am getting, siince my vectors both start out empty and I am trying to add the first float to an empty vert vector inside of an empty shape vector. to do this would you use .push back?  if so is the correct syntax  'myshapes.push_back().verts.push_back(value I want to store)' or is it  'myshapes.push_back(verts.push_back(value I want to store))' or are both incorrect?

Comment: @WarEagleErik, you can use myshapes[0].verts.push_back(x) to add the first item of vertex, and myshapes[0].verts.push_back(y) to add another. if you only have two in total, don't use others. then use myshapes[0].verts[0] to access x and myshapes[0].verts[1] to access y (both read/write possible after you add).

Answer (score 0):

`vector` supports the use of the `[]` operator. The syntax and semantics are very similar to using the `[]` operator with arrays. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at.

As with any struct member, you need to access it by name. `myshapes[i].verts[j] = 4;`.

The general advice given is to use `std::vector` as your default container of choice. Naturally if you have specific needs (like adding/removing items in the middle of the container) other containers may have better performance characteristics.

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  Would this work even if you start out with an empty shape vector? I would think it would not since "i" and "j" in your comment would not exist.  If 'vector<shape> myshapes' starts out empty and 'vector<float> verts' inside of the shape struct is also empty would you have to use '.push_back()' to add the first item?  If so is this the correct syntax:  'myshapes.push_back().verts.push_back(value I want to store)'  or is it like this: 'myshapes.push_back(verts.push_back(value I want to store))'?

Comment: sorry for the poorly formatted comment. what I was trying to say is if they are both initially empty vectors won't the [] not work? In this case do you have to use push back? if so is the correct syntax  `myshapes.push_back().verts.push_back(value I want to store)` or is it  `myshapes.push_back(verts.push_back(value I want to store))` or are both incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

If your vector(s) start out empty, you'll have to add elements to them before you can index into them with [`operator[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator%5B%5D/). This is usually done with [`push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) (to add an existing `shape` object) or [`emplace_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace_back/) (to construct a new `shape` object directly in the vector).

Given `vector<shape> myshapes`, you could add some shapes like this:

```
// add 10 shapes
for (size_t n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
    shape s; // creates a new, blank shape object

    // initialize the shape's data
    s.type = ...;
    s.shapeSize = ...;
    // etc.

    // add verts
    s.verts.push_back(1.0f);
    s.verts.push_back(2.0f);
    s.verts.push_back(3.0f);
    // etc.

    // add the shape to the vector
    myshapes.push_back(std::move(s));
}
```

(Since we're done with `s` on that last line, we can use `std::move`. This allows `push_back` to *move* the shape's data into the vector instead of copying it. Look up *move semantics* for more info.)

Once you have stuff in the vector, you can access elements by index like this:

```
myshapes[index of shape].verts[index of vertex within that shape]
```

Using `[]` with an invalid index or when the vector is empty invokes *undefined behavior* (don't do it or your program will crash/malfunction).